# Getting a div out of another div

Tags: css

I have a div 'offers' inside of a container div and a content div, the container div is 1200px width and  the content div is 100% width with a padding of 1em. I want the 'offers' div to come out of the div's and use the whole width of the screen, I tried it with a position absolute, z-index and width 100% but that is not working. Does anyone has a answer for me?

Comment: Show us your code or make a fiddle demo

Comment: Redesign your page, and not try to do it with not css.

Comment: When you say "not working", what were you expecting and what did you actually get? we need the HTML and CSS!!

Comment: It is working thanks to the comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code I can't give a complete answer, but try `left: 0; right 0;` instead of `width` with the absolute div.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the container, have your 100% div and then open a new container.

The "container" is just a guide not a rule.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VYPYXO)

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  /* for visual reference */
  background-color: #bada55;
}
.full {
  height: 200px;
  /* for visual reference */
  background-color: #663399;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```